# displaying uploaded images

Tags: php

I am trying to create a code which obtains uploaded images, stores them and also displays the image preview and confirms that the image was successfully uploaded.

```
<?php
$name=$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$tmp=$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$error=$_FILES['myfile']['error'];
$path='myweb/';
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path.$name)==1){echo 'success';}else{echo $error;};
echo ('<img src="$path.$name" height="100px" width="100px"/>');
<?php
```

The problem is that images are not displaying.

I have also tried

```
echo ('<img src="$path$name" height="100px" width="100px"/>');
```

but it still doesn't work.

How can I get the images to display?

Comment: Does your script output "success"?

Comment: try to use **.** in the echo statement to concatenate the <img> tag's src and its **$path**  variable

Comment: i tried this `<?php

$path='myweb/';
$name='dotyesttt.jpg';

echo ("<img src=$path$name height=100px width=100px/>" );


?>` and it works fine:(

Comment: yes it does output success.

Comment: i tried cocatinating $path and $name but no success:(

Comment: @aliahmad your problem is solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

problem was with single and double quotes.

```
echo '<img src="' . $path.$name . '" height="100px" width="100px"/>';
```

You have used single quote and because of that it was not taking the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the variable in the printed string like this:

```
echo ('<img src="'.$path.$name.'" height="100px" width="100px"/>');
```

You can read more about it in [the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

If you don't do so, PHP will think that you want to print the text `$path.$name` instead the variables content.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="<?php echo $path,$name; ?>" height="100px" width="100px"/>
```

OR

```
echo '<img src="' . $path.$name . '" height="100px" width="100px"/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between using double "" and single '' quotes.

Double quotes are getting parsed, which means that

```
$variable = 10;
echo "$variable";
```

will output:

```
10
```

Single quotes don't get parsed:

```
$variable = 10;
echo '$variable';
```

will output:

```
$variable
```

you use variables within '' which means they don't get parsed.

Answer (score 0):

i replaced line 13 in above code like so.

`echo (" <img src=$path.$name height=100px width=100px/>");`

And its working now.
Seems like double quotes were the problem here.
I'l read m0re about it.
Thank u s0 much guys u all've been very helpful.:)